# Windows Explorer not responding

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I am running W7 64bit on an AMD Quad 1.8Ghz processor.  I have a 500GB system drive and added a 1TB drive.

Windows Explorer does it's "not responding" thing regularly. I read the other posts and ran SCANNOW and it came back clean. I also ran AUTORUNS and disabled everything that was not windows related.  No luck.

I booted in safe mode and it appears that explorer works, but I don't know why.  I did read a post awhile back that it could be a Service program that makes explorer not respond.  I forgot to bookmark the site and don't remember how to turn off the SP's without crashing the entire system.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.  I have also run CHKDSK on all drives, and there were no errors found.

EDIT:
 It has been in for about 2 years and the problem started about 4 or 5 months ago.

Comment: If you disconnect the newly added 1TB drive, does the problem go away?

Answer (score 0):

When you open Windows explorer, it enumerates all storage hardware connected to the PC including optical drives, it also enumerates network mapped drives and shares, any of the attached storage devices can cause explorer hang if they do not respond in time or have other issues, start disconnecting storage devices and see if the problem stops. This problem is almost always hardware related.

Since it works better in Safe Mode it could be a 3rd party hardware driver or mass storage filter driver, video driver or possibly a network device.

You could boot normally and use msconfig to disable Startup and "Non Microsoft Services" items one at a time to see if you can find the culprit. You have to reboot each time you disable a msconfig item and check explorer behavior.

A methodical process of elimination to find the cause.